# holes in the render

Tags: rendering

I have a a quite simple model, the roof is just a flat mesh with the same material of the walls but, during the rendering there is a black rip in the roof. Is it a bug or a mistake I made?
[image]

I am using Blender 2.82
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you add the material setting and a wireframe view?

Comment: Also make sure that there the clipping ranges are properly set and there are no objects hidden in the viewport that may still appear in the render.

Comment: You can try to save into a different file and remove all the other objects and see if the error still occurs and maybe that way find what causes the issue